# struts 2 tag cause slow performance

Tags: java, struts2

We are building a struts based application, using Geronimo 2.1.3 as the
 application server. In all the JSP pages we are using struts tags. The
 pages are rendered very slowly. Even after pre-compilation there was no
 significant change, the pages are painted very slow.
Any solution for that.
Thanks
Prashant

Comment: Like John said, you need to provide a lot more details. Which tags are you using? Have you used a client-side profiler like page speed to see what the time is being spent on?

Answer (score 2):

If you have `<s:head theme="ajax"/>` it is going to load all javascript that is needed for all special ajax functionality.  Based on your question though there isnt much else that can be told.  More information will help for a better response.